# For ... in not yielding methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, reflection

Given the following:

```
export class MyClass {
    public dataA = 0
    private dataB = 123
    public myMethod(): any {
        return {
            test: 'true'
        }
    }

    constructor() {
        for (const propOrMethod in this) {
            console.log({propOrMethod})
        }
    }
}

const myInst = new MyClass()
```

I run this with `ts-node index.ts` and all i get is:

```
{ propOrMethod: 'dataA' }
{ propOrMethod: 'dataB' }
```

With no reference to `myMethod`. I would like to iterate over all the methods of my class, but they don't appear to exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for..in` iterates over all enumerable properties of the instance and up the prototype chain. But normal methods in a class are not enumerable:

```js
class MyClass {
    myMethod() {
        return {
            test: 'true'
        };
    }
}
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(MyClass.prototype, 'myMethod').enumerable);
```

So it doesn't get iterated over.

If you want to iterate over non-enumerable properties as well, use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` (which iterates over the object's **own** property names, so you'll need to do so recursively if you want all property names anywhere in the prototype chain):

```js
const recurseLog = obj => {
  for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)) {
    console.log(name);
  }
  const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  if (proto !== Object.prototype) recurseLog(proto);
};
class MyClass {
    dataA = 0;
    dataB = 123;
    constructor() {
        recurseLog(this);
    }
    myMethod() {
        return {
            test: 'true'
        };
    }
}
const myInst = new MyClass();
```

You could also make the method enumerable:

```js
class MyClass {
    dataA = 0;
    dataB = 123;
    constructor() {
         for (const propOrMethod in this) {
            console.log({propOrMethod})
        }
    }
    myMethod() {
        return {
            test: 'true'
        };
    }
}
Object.defineProperty(MyClass.prototype, 'myMethod', { enumerable: true, value: MyClass.prototype.myMethod });
const myInst = new MyClass();
```

Or assign the method after the class definition:

```js
class MyClass {
    dataA = 0;
    dataB = 123;
    constructor() {
         for (const propOrMethod in this) {
            console.log({propOrMethod})
        }
    }
}
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = () => ({ test: 'true' });
const myInst = new MyClass();
```

Or assign it to the instance in the constructor:

```js
class MyClass {
    dataA = 0;
    dataB = 123;
    constructor() {
        this.myMethod = this.myMethod;
         for (const propOrMethod in this) {
            console.log({propOrMethod})
        }
    }
     myMethod() {
        return {
            test: 'true'
        };
    }
}
const myInst = new MyClass();
```

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))` seems to be what I was after. Thanks!