# How to get method names of class and superclass in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

Suppose I have a base class `A` and child class `B`:

```
class A {
    a() {
        return;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    b() {
        return;
    }
}
```

and I have an instance of `B`:

```
const b = new B();
```

How do I get all the method names of `b`?

```
const methods = getMethodsOf(b); // Expected: ['a', 'b'];
```

I know how to get the method names that belong to class `B` only, by using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(b))`, but this unfortunately only returns `['constructor', 'b']`.
I also want to get the methods of the super class of `B`. How to achieve this?

Edit: someone marked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544789/get-class-methods-in-typescript) as a duplicate, but it isn't, since that question doesn't involve the superclass.

Comment: No, that doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-methods):

```js
const classMethods = require("class-methods");
class A {
    a() {
        return;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    b() {
        return;
    }
}
console.log(classMethods(B)); //[ 'b', 'a' ]

const b = new B();
console.log(classMethods(b.constructor)); //[ 'b', 'a' ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works with the class `B`, but not with an instance of `b`